# Concatenate string to object method

Tags: php, object

I have

```
    $produse = $this->$table->with('categorie')
                             ->with_deleted()
                             ->get_all();
```

and I need

```
    foreach ($this->$table->belongs_to as $key => $value):
            $with = $produse->with("$key");
    endforeach;

    $produse = $this->$table{$with}
                             ->with_deleted()
                             ->get_all();
```

but after `{$with}` everything is null.

Comment: does $this->table->with($key) is suitable for you ?

Comment: I need `"->with('$key')"` to be concatenated cuz sometimes `$with = "->with('$key')->with('$another_key')";` I have multiple with.

Comment: why don't you end up storing $another_key in $key ? or ->with(isset($another_key) ? $another_key : $key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the `with` method in a loop over the keys,
assuming `$key` is in an array or you can put it in one.

```
$produse = $this->$table

foreach($array as $key){
    $produse->with($key);
}

$produse->with_deleted()
     ->get_all();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, storing function calls in strings is a bad practice. Assuming you can have multiple possibilities for your with method, you should first determine which one you're gonna use :

```
$withKey = $key;
// if you must use another variable, determine which here, the way depends on your needs

//and then call the function
$produse = $this->$table->with($withKey)
    ->with_deleted()
    ->get_all();
```